# disable uibutton whilst still pressed?

Tags: iphone, sdk, uibutton

is it possible to disable a uibutton whilst it is tapped by user?

I use the NBTouchAndHoldButton and in my method I want the button to be disabled when a certain number is reached.

i.e

```
//......
    [touchAndHoldButton addTarget:self action:@selector(countNumbers:) forTouchAndHoldControlEventWithTimeInterval:0.2];

//.....

-(void) countNumbers {

[self countTheNumbers];

if (currentNumber == 10) {
        touchAndHoldButton.userInteractionEnabled = NO;

        }

}
```

So while holding the button down when the number 10 is reached i want the button to be disabled and ignore touches from that point on. In the example above the button still receives input from user until the user lifts finger. then it goes into disable.
Is that possible?

Comment: where the surrent number integer is incremented?when you touch the number should be incremented by 1 ,then only the condition ill work,

Answer (score 0):

```
//..........

[self.btnObj addTarget:self action:@selector(countNumbers) forTouchAndHoldControlEventWithTimeInterval:0.2];

//..............

-(void) countNumbers {
    if (currentNumber == 10) {
        self.btnObj.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
        return;
    }
    [self countTheNumbers];
}
-(void)countTheNumbers{
    currentNumber++;
}
```

Try this.Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using `NBTouchAndHoldButton` available at: https://github.com/balazsnemeth/NBTouchAndHoldButton

In "NBTouchAndHoldButton.h" you need to expose the holdTimer property:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSTimer* holdTimer;
```

Than, in "NBTouchAndHoldButton.m", you need to comment the original `holdTimer` declaration and syntethize the brand new created property:

```
//NSTimer* holdTimer;
@synthesize holdTimer;
```

This way you can invalidate the timer whenever your code reaches a specified criteria. Assuming you button name is `btnStartAnimation`, all you have to do is:

```
[btnStartAnimation.holdTimer invalidate];
```